# Iron router: Is there something that I'm doing wrong here?

Tags: meteor

I want to make it so that when a visitor clicks on a link, they will be taken to a completely different page without using the "yield" that Iron Router does.

The code looks like this:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: "main",
  loadingTemplate: "loading"
});

Router.route("/blog", {name:"blog"});
```

The page loads fine if I add the {{>yield}} in the area where I want the page to load, but in order to load the /blog on a completely new page, I'm not sure how to set it up that way.

The link itself is set up like this:

```
<a href="{{pathFor "blog"}}">
```

Any help will be checked and upvoted.

Comment: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#setting-region-data-contexts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#setting-region-data-contexts) you can easily specify a different layout template per route:

```
Router.route("/blog", function() {
  this.layout('TheLayoutYouWantToUseForBlog');
}, {name:"blog"});
```